# закрепленный комментарий php mysql

Tags: php, mysql

здравствуйте, есть таблица новостей, и есть комментарии, как можно реализовать систему "закрепленный комментарий"? чтобы этот комментарий выводился первый независимо от условия выборки?

аналогично системе вопрос/ответ, лучший ответ всегда выводится первым

Comment: добавьте в таблицу комментариев столбец, в котором будет обозначено закреплен коммент или нет. Измените порядок сортировки чтобы сначала шли закрепленные, потом то что было раньше. В чем проблема у вас собственно возникает? `order by is_pinned desc, id desc`, где `is_pinned` ваш столбец принимающий значение `0` или `1`. либо `null` и `1`, тогда `order by isnull(is_pinned,0) desc, id desc`

Answer (score 1):

У комментария можно поставить флаг закреплен ли коммент **marked boolean**, при выборке сделать двойную сортировку

```
ORDER BY marked DESC, id
```

Закрепленный будет всегда **первым**

Answer (score 0):

Если закрепленный комментарий всегда один, то возможно будет удобнее добавить поле с указанием закрепленного комментария в таблицу новостей. В этом случае, вы всегда сможете получить быстрый доступ к закрепленному комментарию еще на на этапе выборки новостей.